# Accessing vec3b in a vector in opencv

Tags: opencv, c++11, vector

```
vector<Vec3b> dedColors;
```

Could someone please explain me how I can read and write values to the variable dedColors? I need to store 3 values in each of the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it something like this:

```
vector<Vec3b> dedColors;
dedColors.push_back(Vec3b(1,2,3));
dedColors.push_back(Vec3b(4,5,6));
dedColors.push_back(Vec3b(7,8,9));
```

Where `1,2,3`, `4,5,6` etc are the BGR values of the elements that you want to store.

You can read back like this:

```
unsigned char uVal = dedColors[2][1];  // reads '8'
```

Comment: `Vec3b c = dedColors[2];`    Gets the third BGR value. Then, `c[0]` is Blue channel, `c[1]` is Green channel, and `c[2]` is the Red channel.